# Entropy relative to convolution with a Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, information-theory, entropy

Denote by $H(\cdot||\cdot)$ the relative entropy (also known as KL divergence).
If $X$ is a centered random variable and $G_{\sigma^2} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ is a normal random variable with variance $\sigma^2$, it is not hard to show that the expression
$$H(X||G_{\sigma^2}),$$
is minimized when $\sigma^2 = Var(X)$.

Now, let $Y$ be another random variable.
What can be said about
$$H(X||Y+G_{\sigma^2})?$$
Several interesting questions could be:

1. For which $\sigma^2$ is the expression minimized?
2. How will small changes in $\sigma^2$ change the value of $H(X||Y+G_{\sigma^2})?$

Any input or references will be most welcome.

Comment: I think there might be a mistake in your first claim. I believe the KL is minimized when $\sigma^2 = E[X^2]$ (i.e., second moment), not when $\sigma^2 = Var(X)$ (i.e., centered second moment).

Comment: You are very correct. I am however, assuming the variables are centered. Not that it should matter for the discussion.

Comment: even $Y$ is centered ?

Comment: I guess it's a reasonable assumption to make. I'm not sure if it should affect the answer or not.